# Navigating to UITableViewController embedded with UINavigationController

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uinavigationcontroller, appdelegate

I am trying to present a `UITableViewController` and a `UINavigationController` embedded to it programatically. However, it gets displayed without the navigation controller. How can I solve this ?

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {

MyTableViewController *myt = [self.window.rootViewController.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"mytableviewControllerID"];
         UINavigationController *nav = ((UINavigationController*)myt);

        self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];

        self.window.rootViewController = nav;
        [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

return YES;

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your mistake is doing

```
 UINavigationController *nav = ((UINavigationController*)myt);
```

This does not embed your controller in navigation controller. You are just casting your controller to be of navigation controller.

Try this:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {

MyTableViewController *myt = [self.window.rootViewController.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"mytableviewControllerID"];
UINavigationController *nav = [[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:myt];

self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
self.window.rootViewController = nav;
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

return YES;

}
```